# How to change TexField variant on input focus and maintain the focus using Material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When the user focuses on input I want to change the variant on the TextField. Bellow snippet does that, but the input loses focus. you need to click again on input in order to focus and write some text inside

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false)

  return <TextField
    variant={focus ? 'outlined' : 'standard'}
    onFocus={(e) => setFocus(true)}
    value={name}
    name='name'
    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
}
```

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dynamic-variant-7up6q?file=/demo.tsx

My understanding is the following:

TextField component re-renders with new props and is creating a new input element to display while destroying the old one. In this way, the user needs to do 2 clicks on input before texting.

I tried with onClick also, leading to the same result.

Is there a way to obtain these results without losing the focus on input?

Answer (score 0):

Use "useRef" for focusing the input, inputRef prop will help you to set ref. And useEffect to track and update.

```
  const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const onFocus = () => {
    setFocus(true);
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setFocus(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (focus) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [focus]);

  return (
    <TextField
      variant={focus ? "outlined" : "standard"}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      value={name}
      inputRef={inputRef}
      name="name"
      onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can check demo here:
Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dynamic-variant-forked-8pbdi?file=/demo.tsx